# Proof Help for $[(A\cap B = B \cap C)\wedge (A\cup B = B \cup C)] \implies A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$[(A\cap B = B \cap C)\wedge (A\cup B = B \cup C)] \implies A = B$

We must show that our conditions show that $\forall x[x\in A \rightarrow x\in B \wedge x\in B \rightarrow x \in A]$

$x \in A \rightarrow x \in A \cup C \rightarrow x\in B \cup C$ If $x \in B$ we are done If only $x\in C$ then I must find a way to show $x\in C \rightarrow x\in B$ I'm stuck here. Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: Hint: $(A\cap B = B\cap C )\wedge(A\cup B=B\cup C) \implies A=\color{purple}{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(A\cap B = B\cap C )\wedge(A\cup B=B\cup C)$

Now, clearly $A\cup B=B\cup C \iff A\setminus B = C\setminus B\;$ (why?)

So we have $(A\cap B= C\cap B) \wedge (A\setminus B = C\setminus B)$

Now $A = (A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)$

So by substitution $A= (C\cap B)\cup (C\setminus B)$

But $C= (C\cap B)\cup (C\setminus B)$ so then it follows that $A=C$

$$\therefore \quad (A\cap B = B\cap C )\wedge(A\cup B=B\cup C)\implies A=C$$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the \ set operator. I only know union, intersection, symmetric difference, complement and relative complement

Comment: @Dunka The set difference is defined as $A\setminus B = \{x: x\in A \wedge x\notin B\}$, and is sometimes written as $A-B$.  This *is* the relative complement of $B$ in $A$.  $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$.